# How do I move the center of map in EPSG 4326

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, proj

I have Australia, and Samoa and other Oceania territories in a map. If I plot this with EPSG 4326 `proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 + no_defs"` The points fall into the outer edges of the map. This is silly, the islands are close to each other but this projection puts (f.i.) Samoa at -130 and Australia at +120.

How do I move the center (datum?) of the map? For instance still at the equator but through Australia?

Things I've tried:

`map_in_sf %>%
    st_transform("+proj=longlat +lon_wrap=180")`

- lon_0=180
- +over

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the country boundaries on a map you can use the `world2` dataset from the `maps` package, which has longitude from 0-360. If you have some specific spatial format such as `sf` and want to plot with `geom_sf` in `ggplot2`, my [cursory investigation](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/280) suggests there might be/have been some issues with respecting wrapping, though it's hard to verify without your data. Look into `st_wrap_dateline`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'maps'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     map
ggplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  borders("world2", region = c("australia", "new zealand", "samoa"))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This does give me the countries I need, but it does not solve the issue with the data I have.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly it seems to be thing related to this projection. (or rather it is not a projection at all. If I use a different projection it does work.

`st_transform("+proj=mill +lon_0=-250")`

It might be related to WGS84 ?